# How to reset a vector which is was declared globaly

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

when using the fill method or clear the following error appears

```
request for member ‘clear’ in ‘adj’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector [1000005]
```

the declaration is as follows:

```
vector<int> adj[1000005];
```

Comment: Note that `adj` is not a `vector`, but an array of `vector`. Did you mean to write `std::vector<int> adj(1000005);` which would create a `vector` of 1000005 elements, called `adj`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a vector but an array of 1000005 vectors. To properly define a global vector you'll need to use parentheses (or braces):

```
vector<int> adj(1000005);
```